# Parameters corresponding to curl negotiate in requests_kerberos

Tags: python, python-requests, kerberos

Trying to authenticate using kerberos.

My curl command that succeeds is `curl --negotiate -u : -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST URL -d@doc.json`

I tried replicating same using python requests using `auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL, force_preemptive=True)`. I am not sure if I need a different library or if I am setting parameters incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure how to close this question. But for future readers using HTTPSPNEGOAuth from requests_gssapi library helped me get pass the negotiation issue.

Comment: You close the question by *posting a whole answer* for future readers. (Usually you can accept it after a few days if no one posts a better answer, although in this particular case it's hard for anyone else to post an answer at all given the lack of useful info in the question...)